# SQL Server table.Script() method throwing strange exception

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2014

I have a server with a database on it that I can access through SSMS and I am an owner of. Meanwhile in C#, I create an instance of  `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Table` which inherits from `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.TableViewTypeBase`.

`TableViewTypeBase` has a method called [`Script()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.tableviewtabletypebase.script?view=sql-smo-140.17283.0), and as you can see from the link there, the documentation isn't exactly illuminating.

Here's what I'm trying to do: I connect to the server successfully and to the database successfully. I can get a list (or something like a list, a collection maybe) of tables in the database via `database.Tables`. Then I grab a specific table from those Tables and I want to call that `Script()` method on it.

As you might already guess, this isn't code I have written but I'm here now trying to get it to work. For a lot of the tables I've done this with, there are no issues. However, with one of them, I'm getting this error:

> Script failed for Table X

Googling for this leads to a lot of answers about "publications" and "subscriptions" that I don't think apply to my situation, but I'm quickly getting out of my depth. [This link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/dd88985a-5e47-4904-8eda-d41d1e276bdd/replication-failed-on-one-table?forum=sqlreplication) from MSDN says I need to update my "database compatibility level"?

Soooo of course I head on back to Google and find [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/view-or-change-the-compatibility-level-of-a-database?view=sql-server-2017) from the Microsoft Docs, and all is going well until I get to Step 5 and wouldn't you know it—that dropdown is grayed right out. No number is shown there. It looks like this:

[image: compatibility level drop down grayed out SSMS]

And I'm pretty sure it's not a permissions issue because I'm an owner of that database!

So, wise ones: what do you recommend? There just aren't that many answers out there for this particular error and the documentation is basically nothing. I'm running out of ideas.

Comment: Does the database contain a table named X ?

Comment: Try applying the latest Service Pack / Cumulative Update.

Comment: @alexherm yes it does!